# How to transport a verification code securely

Tags: java, objective-c, encryption, client-server, restkit

I'm working atm on a iOS app and a SMS-Based-Verification System to verify users Phone number.

For this propose i m generating a Random number on the device. This number i want to send by SMS again to the device. My Problems is how i could transport this number over the network? If some1 uses Wireshark, he easily can see the Verification-Code. I thought about two ways:

**Way 1 (Device <-> SMS-Gateway):**

Code creation on device -> send to SMS-Gateway-Provider -> validate code that user typed from SMS

**Way 2 (Device -> Server -> SMS-Gateway -> Device <-> Server):**

Request Code-Creation from Server -> Create code (Save in DB + send encrypted code as response back) & send Code to SMS-GW -> Send SMS to device -> check to server if code that user typed is correct <-> true / false send by server back.

Now is there a better or a more easy (more important secure and practical) way? Also i m not sure how to encrypt/decrypt the code. Its a 6 character code that contains only digits.

My Server backend is a Java Jersey RESTful WS.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: i'm confused with way 1: code creation on device, i thought the code should be send to the device

Comment: Yes, when the Code arrives the user have to typeit in my app so I can confirm that the Phonenumber exists. For this propose the device has to know the Code that has been created to compare the one that the user typed with the one that has been created & send by sms.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a security design issue without a related implementation problem. I would consider asking this at http://security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Its Not only a design question. I also want to know like I wrote how to encode/decode plaintext !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way SMS code verification systems normally work is:

1. Device says to server "send me a code".
2. Server generates a code and stores it in the database (either encrypted or hashed with HMAC).
3. Server sends the unencrypted code to the SMS-Gateway (over SSL).
4. Device receives the SMS.
5. User enters the code from the SMS, and device sends the code to the server (over SSL).
6. Server verifies the code from the user against the code stored in the database.
7. Server responds with success or failure.

There's no real reason you need to be generating the code on the device itself, or send the code from the server up to the device. Doing either of these will make the system less secure because the device will know what the code is before receiving it in the SMS. Nor do you need to encrypt the code when you send it from the device to the server (step 5) as long as you use SSL.

Authentication of the code needs to be done on the server side so that you're the only one in control of the authentication process. If you have the mobile app making the authentication decision, you open yourself up to people altering your app or people writing a rogue app to bypass the authentication process.

Comment: Like that. I have to take a closer look at home.

Comment: Could you maybe explain why you recommend HMAC? What is the propose if its all working on server side?

Comment: Even if it's on the server side, you should never store an authentication credential in plain text. If your database were compromised and you were not aware of it, the attacker would have direct access to all the SMS codes. Encryption and HMAC both use a fixed key to derive a value, and you'd store this key in some other location like in a properties file or on the server file system.

Comment: Also, you should use HMAC instead of just straight SHA-1 or something because the domain for your SMS codes is so small (000000 to 999999). It's trivial to calculate every SHA-1 for such a small domain.

Comment: ah! How do a key look like?

Comment: If you have questions about encryption, hashing, keys, etc., I'd suggest doing some research on your own to start with (there's plenty of good content out there already, just need to google it). As for HMAC, start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)

Comment: ty. You helped a lot to go the right way!